# Where does WWW-Authenticate header get added when using WindowsAuthenticationModule

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, windows-authentication

If I set Windows Authentication to true in IIS7 and set Anonymous Authentication to false, I will get a WWW-Authenticate header.  I assume this is the cue to the browser to popup the authentication dialog.  I'm trying to figure out where in the ASP.NET pipeline the WWW-Authenticate header gets set (and what class is responsible for setting it it).  I've done quite a bit of Googling and looking at WindowsAuthenticationModule and UrlAuthorizationModule in reflector but can't seem to pinpoint it!

Comment: I believe this header can also be set by the IIS core engine itself. That being said, .NET Reflector does show references to it: HttpWorkerRequest, HeaderInfoTable, WebHeaderCollection, UnsafeNclNativeMethods, etc... Can you explain a bit more what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several modules in IIS 7 perform tasks related to security in the request-processing pipeline. In addition, there are separate modules for each of the authentication schemes, which enable you to select modules for the types of authentication you want on your server.

The one you are looking for is the WindowsAuthenticationModule, which performs NTLM integrated authentication. It is located in Inetsrv\Authsspi.dll.

The picture below shows the HTTP request processing pipeline mechanism of IIS7.

[image]

For a complete in-depth elaboration, including the above material, visit: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/101/introduction-to-iis-7-architecture/

That should answer all your questions :-)

Comment: Additional: on my Windows7 Home edition PC, running IIS7.5, the Windows Authentication header is set in Inetsrv\authbas.dll, but this is not a .NET assembly and cannot be easily decompiled.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Authentication set in IIS the authentication will occur between the client and IIS.

.NET may access the details when  is set in the web.config but IIS sends the WWW-Authenticate header and manages credential exchange.

See more:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_In_IIS

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Comment: Sorry Bernie, your articles refer to older versions of IIS. The specific way of handling the HTTP request has been reimplemented completely in IIS 7 and newer. See my answer for details.

Comment: @kroonwijk I agree the pipeline is different under IIS7+ but that doesn't mean that the WWW-Authenticate header is created in a ASP.NET module or handler.

Comment: At least the content of the authentication header should be created there, otherwise the 'seperation of concerns' principle of the processing pipeline is violated and the model is not extensible with other authentication models. The generic part of the authentication header (if any) could be done in a central place.